# With deeply nested objects is there a shortcut to auto check each nesting?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

In my applications I have a main configuration document (object) that has some deep nesting. So I find myself typing `config && config.Exports && config.Exports.accounting && config.Exports.accounting.thisIsWhatIWant` a lot.

So my question is, in WebStorm, can I write `config.Exports.accounting.thisIsWhatIWant` and then use a shortcut key or right-click + some menu item to get it to auto expand these?

Comment: Might consider using lodash which has  `has()` and `get()` methods that take string paths as argument https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get. or write a recursive helper function that takes in string path and walks through nesting levels

Comment: This can get ugly for deep nesting. Maybe consider looking at [javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key) as a cleaner alternative.

Comment: Yeah, I had looked at that in the past, but I didn't use it because it seemed to get in the way of tracking down any real problem I might run into. That is why I want to see if there is a way to auto complete from within the editor

Answer (score 0):

Optional chaining wasn't around when I asked this question, but this is the answer.

https://fjolt.com/article/javascript-optional-chaining